# automatically repairing stuck pixels in scan data

Tags: python-3.x, image, automation

I'm working on developing software for an electron microscope.This works by focusing a beam of electrons at a specific part of the sample and then recording the image using a sensor.

The scan data is saved as a 4D array where the first 2 dimensions are the location (x and y) at which the beam was focused and the other 2 dimensions are the raw sensor output which is a 2D image.

while analyzing the data, I realized that there are some stuck pixels which I would ideally be able to repair automatically via software.

Here is an example:
[image]
As you can see, the data shape is 256,256,256,256 which means we scanned 256x256 points and the sensor data is a 256x256 image.
On the right data browser window (called nav), you can see the scan location which is 0,0 (also marked on the left window by scanY and scanX). I drew circles around a few of the stuck pixels. here is another scan location for reference:

[image]

I can automatically detect these pixels by unraveling the sensor data and checking for locations where the scan values are always the same, but I'm not sure how to repair these.

My first guess was reading the data from all the pixels that are next to this pixel and averaging them, then storing the average value instead of the stuck value, but I'm not sure if this is a good approach.

How do professional software such as Photoshop "repair" or "hide" a defect in the picture? Are there any known algorithms for this issue? I did a bit of searching but didn't manage to find much.

Comment: I think you are looking for *"infill"*... or *"inpainting"*.

Comment: Btw, posting of pictures of code is discouraged as they are difficult to run  Also, pictures or screengrabs of pictures are also discouraged as they have extraneous borders, different resolution and size from the actual images you are analysing.

Comment: @MarkSetchell you do reallize not everybody owns an electron microscope or access to data generated by one to run the code? as well as large data sizes generated by them (usually more than 10GB) which requires a lot of time and ram to process, not to mention that the pictures DO NOT SHOW ANY CODE to begin with, since they are meant to demonstrate the issue, not as debugging tool. I'm just asking for algorithms / possible solutions to repairing the images, rather than asking for specific code to be written for me.

Comment: Have a look here... https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html

Comment: That's quite interesting, I can generate a mask but the data types aren't compatible, my data is just a value between 0 and 100 which represents the "signal strength" rather than proper RGB values. I have to see if I can implement their algorithm or somehow convert between the two data types.